# Can you identify the species?

Tags: species-identification

Sighted today. Its feathery tail was moving.

[image]

Comment: Please see https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using your link and a basic Google search using your descriptive words "moth with feathery tail", similar images were found.  It appears to be a female moth of the genus Diaphania.  There appears to be many species in this moth genus, and several look similar. Assuming you live in North America, it is probably Diaphania hyalinata. It is most commonly called "melonworm moth" and looks exactly like your linked image. Apparently they can do garden damage and can be considered a garden pest. That was good coffee.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphania

https://bugguide.net/node/view/237001/bgimage

https://bugguide.net/node/view/7924/bgpage

http://www.growingproduce.com/vegetables/pest-of-the-month-melonworm-2/